# sytanx error running pytest from terminal

Tags: python, bash, command-line, pytest

I'm trying to use pytest with a simple example, saved as "test_lesson1.py" with directory structure as shown below.

```
import pytest

TOL = 2e-2

def squared(x):
    return x**2

def test_squared():
    x = 4
    expected = 16
    computed = squared(x)
    msg = "fail"
    np.testing.assert_allclose(expected, computed, rtol=TOL, err_msg=msg)
```

Example directory structure:

proj 
|--tests 
|--|--test_lesson1.py

On Windows but using Git Bash as a bash terminal, how can I run pytest? Here is what I am entering the terminal:

```
alias py='C:/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/myenv/python.exe'
. C:/Users/name/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate myenv 
cd tests/
py -c "pytest test_lesson1.py"
```

which returns

```
 File "<string>", line 1
    pytest test_lesson1.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(myenv)
```

I can confirm that python works with `py -c "print('hello world')"`, which prints as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pytest` is a command that will execute all tests in all files whose names follow the form `test_*.py` or `\*_test.py` in the current directory and its subdirectories, therefore you don't need `python` to invoke it.

Just run

```
pytest test_lesson1.py
```

On the other hand, `print` is a python function and you need `python` to invoke it.